# set dynamic divs value from dynamic text box using angular typescript

Tags: html, angular, typescript

i have a main **dashboard component** with a 2 buttons and a text
inside that component i have stripedcomponent named app-gamestrip with two divs
this is the scenario i need to accomplish and i don't know how

1. set number 5  in the textbox when clicked the button  set that number to the left div
2. set number 7 in the textbox when clicked the button  set that number to the right div
3. set number 12 in the textbox  when clicked the button add another  new 2 div component(use the same stripedcomponent named app-gamestrip) and set the 12 number to the left div
4. set number 3 in the textbox when clicked the button  set that number to the right div
5. set number 10 in the textbox  when clicked the button add another  new 2 div component(use the same stripedcomponent named app-gamestrip) and set the 12 number to the left div
6. set number 11 in the textbox when clicked the button  set that number to the right div 
   and so on ... for each two numbers enter in the text box

this is the stripedcomponent

```
<div>
  <div class="leftdiv" >
    
  </div>
  <div class="rightdiv" >
   
  </div>
</div>
```

this is the dashborad code html component and the typscript code

```
<app-gamestrip></app-gamestrip>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter a number "   class="form-control" 
name="username"    ><br>
<button   (click)="SetFramePoints()">set frame points</button><br>
<ng-container>
  <button   (click)="loadSingleGame()">load game</button><br>
</ng-container>


 import { Component, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef, 
  ComponentFactoryResolver, ComponentRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
  import { GamestripComponent } from '../gamestrip/gamestrip.component';
  import {  playerprop } from '../models/playerprop';


   @Component({
    selector: 'app-dashboard',
    templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
   })
   export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit  {

  constructor(private cfr: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

  componentRef: ComponentRef<GamestripComponent> | undefined
  @ViewChild('template', {read: ViewContainerRef}) viewTemplate: 
  ViewContainerRef | undefined ;

 ngOnInit(): void
 {
 }
 
 loadSingleGame() {
 const componentFactory = 
  this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory(GamestripComponent);
  if (this.viewTemplate!=undefined)
  {
   this.componentRef = 
   this.viewTemplate.createComponent(componentFactory);
    (this.componentRef.instance as any).loaded.subscribe(() => {
     this.childLoaded = true;
   });
  }
}


SetFramePoints()
{
///how should i implement this code 

}


}
```

please see attached image

[image: please see image for clear understanding]

Comment: Please add your code so we can reproduce your problem and help you. Images don't count.

Comment: To me this looks like a case for an array of left/right tuples that you fill up with the input values. The stripcomponent will list and display all tuples with *ngFor. Please include your code.

Comment: edit: so, you want to put from left to right the value of the textbox when click the button? and when all 2 div are filled create 2 new div and so on?

Comment: please see the attached code